# Date and Time Need to display in input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

```js
    $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  0,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        showMeridian: 1
    });
    $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  0,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        pickerPosition:'bottom-left'
    });
        $('.to_date').datetimepicker({
        language:  'to',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  0,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        pickerPosition:'.date'
    });
    $('.form_time').datetimepicker({
        language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 1,
        minView: 0,
        maxView: 1,
        forceParse: 0
    });
   $('#example12').calendar({
  monthFirst: false
});
```

```css
.form-control .form-control:focus .form-control:active{
    outline: none !important;
    
}

input.form-control:focus 
{
    outline: none !important;
    
}
.field1{background-color:transparent !important; border:0px solid #FFFFFF !important;
border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC !important;outline:none !important; box-shadow:none !important;
    border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;}
    .f10{font-size: 1.0em !important;}
    .box2 input{ background-color:transparent !important; border:0px solid #FFFFFF !important;
border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC !important;outline:none !important; box-shadow:none !important;
    border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.box2 input:focus
{
    background-color:transparent !important; border:0px solid #FFFFFF !important;
border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC !important;border-bottom:2px solid rgba(26,167,227,1.00) !important;
outline:none !important;
}
.box2 input:active
{
    background-color:transparent !important; border:0px solid #FFFFFF !important;
border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC !important; outline:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
                                     <div class="col-sm box2 greyfont14 f9">
                                    
                                <input class="form-control field1 f10 form_date date greyfont14" data-date-format="dd-MM-yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input1" type="text" required autocomplete="off" data-link-format="dd-mmm-yyyy" >
                                 
                                </div>
                                 
                                </div>
</div>
```

Try to insert date and time, and the date format will be like this: dd/mm/yyyy (i.e., May 18, 2023, 6:11 PM)this kind of format is required after the selection of date and time.

The time will only need to display inside the calendar, like if I select the date after that, the same place will display the time along with the pm and am 12 hour formats.

Here I am attaching the image for your reference to help you understand it better.